# How to restore older database in db2 9.7

Tags: database, db2, restore, db2-9.7, roll-forward

When restoring a database in DB2 you need to specify the rollforward. I have created a new database using:

```
db2 RESTORE DATABASE dbname USER  adminuser USING 'adminpassword' FROM 'C:\databases' TAKEN AT 20161231131530 INTO newdbnew without prompting
```

This works correctly, but leaves the newly created db in rollforward pending state.

> DB20000I  The RESTORE DATABASE command completed successfully.

When trying to rollforward to a specified point in time (December 31 2016) I get an error that I should roll forward to a point in time after 08 march 2017 because I have logs up untill that day.

How do I restore and use an older db (even with another name) and keeping the new db?

Comment: What's the backup type (offline or online) and when was it taken?

Comment: Please update your question with the `ROLLFORWARD` command you use and the result of that command.

Comment: @mustaccio I'm sorry I forgot to mention, offline backup

Comment: @IanBjorhovde, I will update my question tommorow morning when I'm at the office again